# Adding Title to Description section (in file Properties) of .png metadata for use as Alt Text when using Report Layout (or print layout)

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have developed multiple reports with great success; however, I would now like to add a unique Title to the Description in the Metadata for each exported .png file. In my review of the file Properties, for each image exported, there appears to be no Description information such as Title, Subject, Ratings, Tags or Comments. I would only require Title in the Description portion of the Metadata (this is not the file name).

Additionally, I would like to automate the generation of unique Titles based attributes in the various layers. These unique Titles would be exported as the Title for each unique png exported. I am familiar with the automation syntax; however, I am not familiar with adding the text (e.g. newly automated Title) into the Title of the Description. My intent is to extract the Title of each png so it can be used as the Alt Text when imported in a PDF or MSWord. When generating reports in QGIS I often have hundreds of individual png files exported so any automation would greatly improve this process. For those not familiar with Alt text, it is used to describe the image for visually impaired individuals when using a text reader.

I have searched on numerous keyword related to Alt Text, metadata, etc. for various leads to a solution but have had no success. I am thinking that this is way above my abilities at this point since the metadata labeling and export process appears to be blackhole.

Comment: KJ- thank you for your insight. How about being able to create the metadata Title for the .png for each unique page when exported from the QGIS report . Any suggestions or additional comments? thanks

Comment: KJ-Thanks again and I am a pioneer.